# How to extract each sheet within an Excel file into an individual csv file as it is without appending any column or row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

[image]I'm trying to extract each sheet in an Excel file into multiple CSVs.
For example Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 from Sample_1.xlsx into Sheet1.csv, Sheet2.csv and Sheet3.csv
The code I run is as below :

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_excel('Sample_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for sheet_name, data in dfs.items():
    data.to_csv(f"{sheet_name}.csv")
```

It outputs all of the three CSVs as desired but each csv **has an extra column** (column A) with index starting **0,1,2..n** . Why is that happening? and How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `index` parameter of [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) as False

Replace :

```
data.to_csv(f"{sheet_name}.csv")
```

By :

```
data.to_csv(f"{sheet_name}.csv", index=False)
```